# Authenticating OpenBSD against Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, authentication, kerberos, openbsd

**Edit:** Reformatted this as Q&A. If anyone can change this from Community Wiki to a typical question, that's probably more appropriate as well.

How can I authenticate OpenBSD against Active Directory?

Comment: Very nice! That looks very thorough and well written. I don't use OpenBSD, but the AD parts look spot-on.

Comment: +1 for a nice guide, although it is not really a question.

Comment: You should change this into a Question & Answer format.

Comment: Changed, though it's still a Community Wiki. If someone else can change that, go ahead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Preface**

Authenticating against Active Directory with Kerberos is pretty simple on systems using PAM, but OpenBSD doesn't and makes it more difficult. From a tcpdump, it looks like the PAM systems are just doing pre-authentication while OpenBSD's bsd_auth system is using the whole Kerberos authentication process.

Anyway, this took me a while to figure out so hopefully some concise instructions will save you time.

A few quick notes before we begin:

- Users must exist on the OpenBSD system before attempting to login. They are not autocreated.
- If you want users autocreated, look into Samba/Winbind. I've had nothing but trouble (inexplicable crashes, serious log spamming, unreliable authentication) from it, so I only use it when I have to.
- This was tested on OpenBSD 4.5 and Windows Server 2003. I'm pretty sure it'll work with Win2k, but YMMV.
- This version of OpenBSD uses Heimdal 0.7.2. Everything here aside from the paths and login.conf stuff will probably work on other *nixes running the same Heimdal, but again, YMMV.

**Instructions**

These steps assume you are trying to authenticate myuser@myhost.fqdn against the domain EXAMPLE.COM. The domain controller is pdc.EXAMPLE.COM.

1. Create an Active Directory User account named *myhost* (that's not a typo, these instructions won't work with a Computer account). Disable password expiration and don't let the user change its own password. Set the password to whatever you like - it'll be changed soon.
2. It's probably a good idea to create the User account under a new OU, remove it from the Domain Users group and add it to a dedicated group. This is all a matter of taste and your security layout.
3. On pdc.EXAMPLE.COM, download and install Windows Server Support Tools (specifically, you'll need ktpass.exe)
4. On pdc.EXAMPLE.COM, run:

   > ktpass -out c:\temp\myhost.keytab -princ host/myhost.fqdn@EXAMPLE.COM -mapuser myhost -pType KRB5`_`NT_PRINCIPAL +rndpass

   This updates the myhost user's password to something random (+rndpass), maps
   the Kerberos principal "host/myhost.fqdn@EXAMPLE.COM" to the user "myhost" in
   Active Directory, and then dumps the principal and private key info into the
   -out keytab file.
5. Securely copy c:\temp\myhost.keytab to myhost and delete the file from pdc.EXAMPLE.COM
6. On myhost, add the AD keytab to your main keytab:

   > ktutil copy /path/to/myhost.keytab /etc/kerberosV/krb5.keytab
7. Configure /etc/krb5.conf. Below is the bare minimum that you need. There's a lot of options available, take a look at the manpage for more details. This just sets the maximum acceptable clock skew to 5 minutes, makes EXAMPLE.COM the default realm, and tells Kerberos how to translate between DNS and Kerberos realms.

   > [libdefaults]
   >   clockskew = 300
   >   default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
   >
   > [realms]
   >   EXAMPLE.COM = {
   >   default_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
   >   }
   >
   > [domain_realm]
   >   .EXAMPLE.COM = EXAMPLE.COM
8. Verify that you can get a ticket:

   > `# kinit Administrator@EXAMPLE.COM`
   >   `Administrator@EXAMPLE.COM's Password:`
   >   `# klist`
   >   `Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0`
   >   `Principal: Administrator@EXAMPLE.COM`
   >
   > `Issued           Expires          Principal`
   >   `Jun  4 21:41:05  Jun  5 07:40:28  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM`
9. Modify /etc/login.conf to use Kerberos authentication. Your exact login.conf configuration will vary depending on how you use your system, but to go from a vanilla install to using Kerberos, just edit and comment this line under the default login class:

   > `:tc=auth-defaults:\`

   And add above it:

   > `:auth=krb5-or-pwd:\`

   This checks Kerberos first unless the user is root. If Kerberos fails, it will use local passwords.
10. Add the users you'd like to authenticate on this host. Leave the passwords blank unless you want them to be able to use both Active Directory and local passwords (not recommended).

    You can blank existing users' passwords "chpass `<user>`" and replacing the "Encrypted password:" value with an asterisk (*)
11. Test SSH and Sudo. Both should work flawlessly with your Active Directory credentials.

That's all there is to it.

**Links**

A couple useful sites:

- [Step-by-Step Guide to Kerberos 5 Interoperability | Microsoft Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742433.aspx)
- [Creating a Kerberos service principal name and keytab file | IBM Knowledge Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tsec_kerb_create_spn.html)

Comment: Looks like 2008 R2 has ktpass.exe baked in.  Maybe 2008 as well, can't say for sure at this stage.  If anyone can clarify, that would be great.

Comment: Furthermore, in order to do this with 5.7 onwards, you'll need to install the Heimdal package - it was removed from base in 5.6.

Comment: Addendum to previous comment - you'll also have to install the login_krb5 package and copy the `login_krb5-or-pwd` to `/usr/libexec/auth` - also configuration files and keytab are now in `/etc/heimdal` and not in `/etc/kerberosV` as in previous OpenBSD releases.

Answer (score 5):

An update to the instructions above as a few things have changed since then.

In OpenBSD 5.6, a decision was made to remove Heimdal from the base distribution due to concerns about code quality and nobody being willing to spend the time to audit it.  In 5.7 it was made available as a package (For 5.6 you'll need to build from source or figure out how to re-enable it in source).  So, before following the instructions above, the following additional steps will need to be completed:

-3. Install the `heimdal` and `login_krb5` packages from your favourite mirror.

-2. Copy `/usr/local/libexec/auth/login_krb5*` to `/usr/libexec/auth`.

-1. If you intend to use the heimdal tools a lot, add `/usr/local/heimdal/bin` to your system path.  Otherwise, be sure to reference the tools with their full path when using them.

Also, the `krb5.conf` and `krb5.keytab` files go into `/etc/heimdal` now.